# Paired T-Test and general linear hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have a paired sample with 2 groups and want to figure out wether the mean of one group is twice the mean of the other group. There is the concept of general linear hypothesis of the form H0: $R\mu = r$ with $R$ being an $q\times 2$ matrix of specified hypothesis, i.e. in my case $R$ would be the vector $(1,-2)'$ and $r=0$. Eventually an F-test is used to test H0.

Regarding the fact that the resulting F-statistic of the above approach is just identical to the F-statistic for independant samples, I wonder wether general linear hypothesis only work with independant samples?

What would be the correct way to test wether one mean is the twice the other mean for 2 groups of a paired sample.

Best regards

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "dependent groups"?

Comment: sure. I actually just meant that the samples for both groups come from the same population and are matched, i.e. I have a paired sample.

Comment: Thank you--so you really have *one group* of pairs, not two groups of pairs!

Comment: thank you for making that point clear. I have edited the post. I hope it is more clear now.